# Substitute function gives too few arguments error

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I want to extract the text after the last space with this code I found:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)
```

But it keeps saying I have entered too few arguments for the second `SUBSTITUTE` function. I understand this function has 4 arguments where the last one (Instance_num) is supposed to be optional...in the code there are only 3 and looks like my Excel is missing the last one...any guess why?

Comment: I get no error when testing the formula, do you use `;` instead of `,` for the delimiter?

Comment: You might use: `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",1000)),1000))`

Comment: When you say `extract` do you mean you want all but the last word, or do you mean you only want the last word?  Your formula returns all but the last word, Rory's return just the last word.

Comment: I, too, do NOT get an error with the formula you have posted.

Comment: Ok, it worked today. I'm using Excel in a different language and mixed the local name of the function with a different one...